# How to get the mean value of a column depending on another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

I am currently struggling to get a mean value within a data frame.

---

The df is built like that:

```
'data.frame':   365 obs. of  5 variables:

$ Day      : chr  "01" "02" "03" "04" ...

$ Month    : Factor w/ 12 levels "01","02","03",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

$ Year     : chr  "2019" "2019" "2019" "2019" ...

$ XXX      : int  2 4 5 5 7 6 6 7 6 6 ...

$ Weekday  : Factor w/ 7 levels "Monday","Tuesday",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 ...
```

I would like to get the mean for the value XXX but only for the first month (my_data$Month == "01"). I tried filtering it with dplyr but could not figure it out..

(For understanding: for each day there is one value in XXX, the df is for one entire year)

Can someone help? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try `with(df, mean(XXX[Month == "01"]))` or using `dplyr` `df %>% filter(Month == "01") %>% summarise(Mean = mean(XXX))`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: akrun's answer will work. I assume if you are this new, his use of pipes is probably going to mess with you. Try filtering your dataframe using dplyr like this: firstMonthDF <- filter(df, Month=="01"). Then you can easily take the mean of the column.

Comment: @akrun how would you do it if it would be needed for several months with(df, mean(XXX[Month == c("01", "03")])) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This R base solution should do it:

```
mean(df$XXX[df$month=="01"], na.rm = T)
```

Explanation:

You use the function `mean`to calculate the average of the variable `XXX`in your dataframe `df`, using the argument `na.rm = T`to make sure missing values (`NA`s) are removed for that calculation, but subset the dataframe on those rows that have the value `01`in column `month` so that the mean is calculated **only** on the corresponding values in column `XXX`.

**EDIT**:

Just in case you want to calculate the means not just for one month but all months, you could do this in one go using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(month ~ XXX, data = df, mean)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Thanks as well for the further explanation and addition regarding the aggregate function.Now I can finally dig deeper into the project, much appreciated! :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Do feel free to also click  the upward arrow if the answer was useful to your question.